# Mysql database table design

Tags: mysql, database-design

Users on my site are shown a list of items. The list they see is based on criteria they have completed in a form - they're receiving suggestions if you like.

Now, if a user doesn't want to receive a certain suggestion again, i want them to be able to stop it from showing up.

So, do i create an exceptions table which simply has a user id number and suggestion id number per row and search that before giving suggestions..meaning if the user has previously said no then skip to next suggestion.

Or, do i have a table with a row per user which has their user id and a field of all their exceptions, maybe comma separated or enclosed in[] and do a "where in" search to see if an exception is there - if the latter though and the user decides they do want a particular suggestion at a later date, its easier to get it out of a row per suggestion table as opposed to a field where they are, in fact i wouldn't know if thats even possible.

All advice welcome.

Comment: Never ever put more than one piece of information into one field, if you want to access it separately. Just don't.

Comment: If you're not showing the user a given suggestion how will they know they want to see it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a many-to-many relationship between users and preferences/exceptions.  I'd rather do that than the IN idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a table of "available suggestions" with a suggestion reference and a user reference. so for each user there would be one record for each suggestion available to them. When a user user clicks no, then that record can be deleted from the available suggestions.

Hope this makes some kind of sense.